# AngularJs how to pass Json String into $scope.msg=msg.data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
public JsonResult Authe(string Email, string Password, bool ? Active) {
    var x = (from n in db.Authntications where n.Email == Email && n.Password == Password select n).FirstOrDefault();
    if (x != null) {
        var xx = (from n in db.Authntications where n.Email == Email && n.Password == Password && n.Active == Active select n).FirstOrDefault();
        if (xx == null) {
            msg = "Your A/c not activated....";
        }
    } else
        msg = "Your Account Details Not Valid  please check Details You mentiond...";
    return new JsonResult {
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

**AngularJs**

```
var ZmrSer = MyAuthneticService.Authen(Sucess);
$scope.msg = msg.data; 
$('#modalSuccess').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `Json` from your action method with allowing get behavior.

```
return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```